# Add event listener to DOM elements based on class

Tags: javascript, html, css, listener

I have a table, where each `tr` and `td` have only classes, I have a problem with selection of  `td` element having the class I need
HTML:

```
<table>
 <tr class="data">
  <td class="cell">1</td>
  <td class="cell2"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="data">
  <td class="cell">2</td>
  <td class="cell2"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

When mouseover `td` with `class="cell"`  I have to get text between `td` on which my mouse and do something with this. This should be done with pure JavaScript, without frameworks. I tried:

```
var cell = document.querySelector('.cell');

function callback(){ //do something }
cell.addEventListener('mouseover',callback(),false);
```

It doesn't work, or maybe I did mistakes?

Comment: You need to loop through the node list and add the event listener to each one.

Comment: In addition to what @oGeez mentioned, there are also some addition issues. 1) You need to pass the function to `addEventListener`, which means using `callback` instead of `callback()`. The braces actually call the function, so you're passing the returned value. 2) `querySelector` only returns the *first* matching element, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector).

Comment: I don't know why, but `var cell = document.querySelector('.cell');` returns `null`

Comment: It returns `null` when no element is found. When it finds an element, it returns the element. This means the element doesn't exist at the time when your script runs.

Comment: ok, for example I did so var `cell = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');` `function callback(){alert("working111");}` `for(var j = 0; j < cell.length; j++){
    cell[i].addEventListener('mouseover',callback,false);
}` but nothing changed, how i understand , right now when I over my mouse on element with `class="cell"` there should be an alert, but nothing happening

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The following will only select the first element with `class='cell'`.

```
document.querySelector('.cell');
```

For adding event listener to all such elements, use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll),
which will return a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) (*a kind of array of inactive DOM elements*) having `class='cell'`. You need to iterate over it or access specific element using it's index.

For example:

```
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');
cells.forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener('mouseover', callback, false));
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/hkDg4/)

Answer (score 10):

I would rather use event delegation for this.

```
document.getElementById('your-table').addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
    var t = e.target;

    if (t.classList.contains('cell')) {
        console.log(t.textContent);
    }
});
```

However *"It doesen't work, or maybe I did mistakes?"*

- `querySelector` returns a single element.
- `cell.addEventListener('mouseover',callback()`, here `callback()` calls the callback function right away and that's not what you want. You want to pass the function reference so remove the `()`.

Note that even if you use `querySelectorAll` which returns a node list, it doesn't implement the [Composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) so you cannot treat a list as a single element like you would do with a jQuery object.

Comment: This'll work only if there aren't any elements nested in the `td.cell`. Otherwise, the `e.target` will be off. And `IE9` doesn't have `.classList`, though it can be shimmed.

Comment: @cookiemonster We have to stop caring about these old browsers ;) Also, the `mouseover` event will correctly bubble up and `innerText` will strip off any HTML, so I do not see how it will not work. I do not see the advantage of attaching a listener directly on the element over event delegation in this case.

Comment: You're right. The event should only fire on entry into the `td.cell`, so the descendants aren't relevant. `t.innerText` doesn't work in Firefox, so `.textContent` should probably be used, but that's beyond the question. I still wouldn't use delegation for something like this since the handler is firing constantly for every element in the table that the mouse happens to enter, but since you're only testing the `e.target`, it isn't so bad I guess. +1

Comment: @cookiemonster I really doubt it could have any noticable negative performance impact, unless the DOM structure would be extremely deep  . On the other hand, this solution will scale way better with a lot of rows because it's memory-efficient and you do not have to loop to install handlers on every element.

Comment: It's no more memory efficient than assigning the handler to each row. And it's less memory efficient because of the creation of the `.classList` objects, but as I said you're only testing the one element instead of using a jQuery-like approach where multiple elements may be checked, so it isn't so bad.

Comment: @cookiemonster I am not sure to understand your point of view. "It's no more memory efficient than assigning the handler to each row" I haven't profiled the memory, but I believe that even if the same listener function is reused, calling `addEventListener` must add an entry to some internal data structure and hold memory as long as it's stored. If you have 1000 rows, that would mean 1000 entries while just a single one with event delegation. Also, "less memory efficient because of the creation of the .classList" do you mean that `classList` is lazy-init and doesn't exists unless accessed?

Comment: Yes, a `classList` property doesn't exist on an element. It's found in the prototype chain, which would mean that it's a *getter* property, so the object must be created on the fly. I suppose it's possible that an implementation might maintain some internal cache of all `classList` objects for all elements, but if that was the case, I would imagine they'd just store it directly on the element.

Comment: @cookiemonster You have an interesting point. Then it would be **slightly** less efficient than I thought, however do not forget that only `<td>`'s that are getting hovered will use more memory and I still feel that event delgation would be better when there's a lot of elements.

Comment: @cookiemonster Hum, how do you explain this? It doesn't seem to be a *getter* like you said `document.createElement('div').hasOwnProperty('classList'); //true`

Comment: Which browser? I get `false` in Firefox. And the `.classList` will be created on nested elements of the `<td>` as well since that's how it was determined if the `e.target` was the desired element.

Comment: I see that chrome does create a `classList` for every element. Or at least it seems to. `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(document.body, "classList")` shows a `value` and not a `get/set`. That does make it more compelling.

Comment: @cookiemonster In Chrome Version 35.0.1905.2 canary ... it depends on implementation details then and starts to be quite complex to measure ;) Honestly I cannot tell for sure, but I can find many resources stating that event delegation is better...  ["event delegation is typically more performant than binding each td individually"](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/05/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/) or [Takes up less memory.](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/30/event-delegation-in-javascript/) to list a few.

Comment: In the first article, he's using jQuery, so it's an entirely different event system abstracted on top of the native one. However he didn't really give any reason or benchmarks. jQuery's delegation in particular can be expensive since it tests all elements from the `e.target` to the bound element against the provided selector. Taking a look at the second article now...

Comment: The single point the second article seems to make is that it'll require less memory to bind a single function that it will to create multiple functions. Certainly that's true, but it doesn't have much to do with the question here where the function is reused. And his delegation example is ultra simple. I have nothing against delegation. I'd just normally not use it on rapidly firing events if possible.

Comment: ...he does however bring up a relevant point. *"A word of caution, though, mouseover and mouseout are difficult to handle via event delegation due to their nature (the mouse is considered “out” when it moves from a container to its child)."*. The `mouseover` is going to fire not only when entering the `td` from the outside, but also when entering it after leaving a nested element. This may not be desired. http://jsfiddle.net/F3KPG/

Answer (score 3):

Most modern js environments now support [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) iteration, so you can now do this like:

```
for (var cell of document.querySelectorAll('.cell')) {
  cell.addEventListener('mouseover',callback,false);
}
```

This might even work in a single line:

```
 document.querySelectorAll('.cell').map(cell=>cell.addEventListener('mouseover', callback, false));
```