# Need help toggling dropdown menus using the same class (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get this to work for all elements using the class-name '.sub-menu-parent', but I can only get it to work for the first instance of it.

I have tried using a for loop with the index of parentClass, but it doesn't seem to work. Same goes with the '.sub-menu-child' class.

## HTML

```
        <nav>
            <div class="row">
                <img src="resources/img/logos/HTH_Logo_1_2.png" alt="A logo that says 'hearts that heal'" class="logo">
                <ul class="main-nav">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub-menu--parent">About Us <i class="ion-android-arrow-dropdown"></i></a>
                        <ul class="drop-down-main sub-menu--child">
                            <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Mission Statement</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Vision Statement</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Our Values</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Goals</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Objectives</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub-menu--parent">Photo Gallery <i class="ion-android-arrow-dropdown"></i></a>
                        <ul class="drop-down-main sub-menu--child">
                            <li><a href="#">Group Photos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Retreat Photos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Members Photos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Honorary Members Photos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Our Beloved Children</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Activities and Sponsorship Photos</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

## CSS

```
/* ----- MAIN NAV ----- */

.main-nav   {
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 32.5px;
}

.main-nav li    {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;

}

.main-nav li a:link, 
.main-nav li a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff; 
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 80%;  
    background-color: #c95a6c;  /* #484066 */
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.main-nav li a:hover, 
.main-nav li a:active {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #c95a6c;
}

/* ----- For colors ----- */

.main-nav-color:focus {
    color: #c95a6c !important; 
    background-color: #fff !important;  /* #484066 */
}


/* ----- NESTED NAV ----- */

.drop-down-main {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9990;
    background-color: #fff; 
    display: none;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #484066;
    border-top: none;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}

.drop-down-main li  {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #484066;
    width: 100%;

}

.drop-down-main li a:link, 
.drop-down-main li a:visited {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #c95a6c; 
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 80%;  
    background: none;  /* #484066 */
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 5px 24px 5px 5px;
}

.drop-down-main li:hover, 
.drop-down-main li:active {
    background-color: #c95a6c;
}

.drop-down-main li a:hover, 
.drop-down-main li a:active {
    color: #fff;
}

.drop-down-main li:first-child {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #484066;
}

.drop-down-main li:last-child {
    border: none;
}
```

## Javascript

```
var menuToggle = (function() {
    var DOMstrings = {
        displayToggle: 'show',
        dropParent: '.sub-menu--parent',
        dropChild: '.sub-menu--child',
        colorToggle: 'main-nav-color',
    };

    var parentClass = document.querySelector(DOMstrings.dropParent);
    var childClass = document.querySelector(DOMstrings.dropChild);


    parentClass.addEventListener('click', toggleDropdown, false);

    function toggleDropdown() {
        childClass.classList.toggle(DOMstrings.displayToggle);
        parentClass.classList.toggle(DOMstrings.colorToggle);
    };

    window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        if(event.target !== parentClass && event.target.parentNode !== parentClass) {
            childClass.classList.remove(DOMstrings.displayToggle);
            parentClass.classList.remove(DOMstrings.colorToggle);
        }
    });   
})();
```

I have also tried using querySelectorAll but it seems you can't use classList Methods with it.

Comment: Can you post your css?

Comment: @JonathanChaplin Updated with css

Comment: I've updated my answer, see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `querySelectorAll`

Based from this answer: [Add event listener to DOM elements based on class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767609/add-event-listener-to-dom-elements-based-on-class)

> `document.querySelector('.class-name');` Will only select the first element having `class='class-name'`.
>   For adding event listener to all such elements, use `querySelectorAll()`

And then update the code where you attach the listener.

```
var parentClasses = document.querySelectorAll(DOMstrings.dropParent);

for (var i = 0; i < parentClasses.length; i++) {
    parentClasses[i].addEventListener('click', setupEventListener(parentClasses[i]), false);
}

function setupEventListener(element){
    return function(){
        toggleDropdown(element);
    }
}

function toggleDropdown(element) {
    // since `ul` is a sibling of `a` 
    element.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle(DOMstrings.displayToggle);
    element.classList.toggle(DOMstrings.colorToggle);
};
```

I believe this should work for your current implementation, however this doesn't include code for toggling the display off.

Comment: Im getting this error when I enter the code above: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined
    at toggleDropdown (scripts.js:61)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (scripts.js:52)

Comment: oh, i see, because you have `parent` class in the `a` element. i'll update my answer.

Comment: thanks but with the update code still getting error: Cannot read property 'nextElementSibling' of undefined

Comment: I've updated again my answer, I tried it in jsfiddle, I'll try to work around toggling the display off.

Comment: Thanks, that works for toggling it on and off using the element. Why is this different than the previous example? Aren't you just returning a function through another function? What makes this work but not the other way? It's a bit confusing to me.

Comment: My previous post used a closure and inside it, it was using `parentClasses[i]` (which is not in its scope but in its outer scope), the closure always remembers the current value of `i`, since the last value of `i` in the `for` loop will be equal to the length of `parentClasses`, it will always use that `i` for all the iteration, thus there's always an `undefined` error. (array[length_of_array] => out of bounds). read more about closures in javascript.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thanks